# How to sort strings by part of these strings?

Tags: javascript

I have got an array of objects. Every object has an id, which looks something like this: "Device/1" or "Device/7". In my case the array that I receive is unsorted and I am trying to sort it by the number after the "/". I know it is possible by implementing a bubble sort for example by myself, but is it possible to achieve my goal using the javascript sort() method?

Comment: do you want to sort only by the number or do you have more prefixes?

Comment: `.sort((a,b)=>+a.split("/")[1]-b.split("/")[1])`

Comment: ^ Not terribly efficient. May be better to "pre-split" the strings and sort that instead.

Comment: Please create a [mcve] with a sample of the object array.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol thanks, did exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the work :)

```js
let arr = [{ id: 'Device/2' }, { id: 'Device/1' }]

arr.sort((a, b) => parseInt(a.id.split('/')[1]) - parseInt(b.id.split('/')[1]))

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: @exside instead of a.split, I had to write a.id.aplit since a and b are objects. The template was what I was searching for the most

Comment: @Ognian Baruh are you sure you need to `split` and `parseInt` all object id's, sounds quite inefficient... as I wrote below, if your ID's all look the same, you don't need to do that overhead.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a sort function to `.sort()`:

```js
const arr = [
  {id: 'Device/7'},
  {id: 'Device/3'},
  {id: 'Device/1'},
  {id: 'Device/5'},
];

console.log(arr.sort((a,b) => a.id.localeCompare(b.id)));
```

if your `id`s are consistent you do not need any splitting...

Comment: What if `Device` is not always `Device`?

Comment: Then OP should specify that clearly in his question I think but regardless, with a small change to the sort function it would be solved!